# Python - How to change column width in a pdf table in order to fit everything?

Tags: python, report, fpdf

How can I change the columns width of the tables in the code below in order to fit all text? The first column needs to be larger than the second and third row. For now the columns width is distributed evenly.

Code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
pdf = FPDF()

alfa = 5
lasna = 5

pdf.add_page() 
  
pdf.set_font("Times", size = 16) 

TABLE_COL_NAMES = ("Propriedade", "Valor", "Unidade")
TABLE_DATA = (
    ("Ângulo da vertente", str(alfa), "º"),
    ("Comprimento de cada asna", str(lasna), "m"),
)


pdf.set_font("Times", size=16)
line_height = pdf.font_size * 2
col_width = pdf.epw / 4  # distribute content evenly

def render_table_header():
    pdf.set_font(style="B")  # enabling bold text
    for col_name in TABLE_COL_NAMES:
        pdf.cell(col_width, line_height, col_name, border=1)
    pdf.ln(line_height)
    pdf.set_font(style="")  # disabling bold text

render_table_header()
for _ in range(1):  # repeat data rows
    for row in TABLE_DATA:
        if pdf.will_page_break(line_height):
            render_table_header()
        for datum in row:
            pdf.cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1)
        pdf.ln(line_height)

pdf.output("Relatório_TED.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out what is the longest width of each column and then  you can use the FPDF built in function

getstringwidth to calculate the max width of each column is required.

only major issue would be to deal with situation where if all 3 columns width together is less then the allocated space you will need to add a buffer between each column, and vise versa if the column width of all 3 together is too wide for the pdf then you will need to figure out what to do in those situation.

Documentation - > http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).